# Ubuntu + MySQL remote connections

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I run two servers one being a web hosting and one being a VPS. I want to use my MySQL server on my web hosting and done everything possible but it still will not work. I started by running the mysql command to grant privileges and it showed that the command went through fine although I still got a refused connection on my web server. I then got told to comment out bind_address in the config but once again it failed.

How can I go about fixing this?
Thanks.

Comment: I think there is a configuration setting inside the mysql server where it defines whether it allows remote connections or not.

Comment: I can't seem to find that.

Comment: does the user have permission? '{user}'@'*'?

Comment: It does indeed but I didn't add @* I added @ (web server ip)

Comment: Please post the error code. Generally while creating users in MySQL you can set required permissions for remote access. Setting bind_address =0.0.0.0 helps in MySQL server listening on any IP.

Comment: So I made a test script to ensure that it would work when I set it up on php for the web server and it is just returning this

Comment: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in /home/slashy/slashy.co.uk/cancel.php:7

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow mysql to accept requests from remote not only localhost.

To do that you should edit `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and change from:

`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

to:

`bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

and restart the mysql server with this command: `systemctl restart mysql.service`

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it did not work :( I tried it earlier on today and just re-tried it now

Comment: When adding a user to mysql instead of IP add ```@'%'``` to allow access from any host.

Comment: What does this ```netstat -tulnp | grep mysql``` return?

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21020/mysqld

Comment: Ok, that means that your mysql server is running as it should be. Can you connect to your mysql as root from the server terminal?

Comment: Yes I can connect to the root user fine from my VPS terminal

Comment: add user like this ```CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';```

Comment: I added the user and tried a new connection but did not work :/

Comment: add the permissions for the newly created user on the database as such: ```GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';```

Comment: At this point, I can't really help you. Maybe you should try again from scratch. First install mysql and open port 3306 to firewall, enable connection from 0.0.0.0 and then create the user and grant the permissions. Maybe you did something wrong in the process?

Comment: No problem, comeback please if you fix it !